# Как сделать, чтобы бин создавался не на этапе создания контекста, а при первом обращении к нему?

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, bean

Какая аннотация в Spring отвечает за это?

Comment: это называется ленивая инициализация - @Lazy

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо. Это то, что я искал

Comment: а разве пользовательские бины как-то иначе создаются ?